# Search result links from Google Custom Search not working when viewed in IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, google-search-api

One of the community sites I work on currently has this issue when viewing search results from Google CS in IE6.

For example [these results](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/search/?cx=000517265726492607871%3Agqdiynsp-y0&cof=FORID%3A9&q=sql&sa=Go#1062). Attempting to click on any result doesn't provoke the browser into following the link. Strangely though, shift clicking or right clicking and opening in a new window both work.

Has anybody seen anything like this before? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: IE6 must die :p

Also, It work on my pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a potential solution:

> Replace the following line of code:
>
> ```
> var a=encodeURIComponent||escape;
> ```
>
> With:
>
> ```
> var a=encodeURIComponent;
> ```
>
> Or:
>
> ```
> var a=escape;
> ```

From this [Google Support thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/customsearch/thread?tid=5807df100fc6f102&hl=en).

Note that this fixed problems on specific `IE6` version:

```
6.0.2900.2180.xpsp_sp2_gdr.080814-1233
```

I tested your example page with `IE6` version:

```
6.0.2900.5512.xpsp_sp3_gdr.090206-1234CO
```

And had no problems loading results or following result links.

If the above doesn't help, make sure the **Navigate subframes across different domains** security setting is set to **Enable**.  See [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-custom-search-results/browse_thread/thread/eb3633e43ce7576e/57e1b4fbe90a1622?lnk=gst&q=links+not+clickable&rnum=5#57e1b4fbe90a1622) for more details.

Hope this helps!